# How to extract ul that comes after a particular tag (HTML Parsing)

Tags: html, jsoup, html-parsing

From the below HTML snippet I want to extract ul with all li (as highlighted) which comes just after h2 tag which has span id="See_also"

[image: html]

I am using Jsoup for HTML parsing in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after exploring the documentation of Jsoup I found the solution:

```
Elements ul= html.select("h2:has(span:contains(See Also))+ul");
```

[image: Output]